# Converting lowercase to uppercase letters and printing them

Tags: c, arrays, loops

When I convert and print it in the same loop i get the result plus a garbage that I don't know from where it came.
Example:

**Input:**

```
char array_ch[]={'A','B','C','D','E'};
int i=0;
for(i;array_ch[i]!='\0';i++){
  array_ch[i]=array_ch[i]+32;
  printf("%c",array_ch[i]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
abcde`H��A���/��u�$(!
```

And if I print it in another loop its ok:

**Input:**

```
char array_ch[]={'A','B','C','D','E'};
int i=0;
for(i;array_ch[i]!='\0';i++){
  array_ch[i]=array_ch[i]+32;
}


for(i=0;array_ch[i]!='\0';i++){
  printf("%c",array_ch[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

**Output:**

```
abcde
```

Comment: change to `char array_ch[]={'A','B','C','D','E', '\0'};` or `char array_ch[]="ABCDE";`

Comment: It would be easier to determine the size of the array with sizeof() and use it for the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have undefined behavior. The problem is your loop:
it looks for a \0 and there is none. So  with sheer luck you see the problem it's worse with the run you think works ok, because well it looks as if it's ok but it's just a problem waiting to be happen.

So write:char array_ch[]={'A','B','C','D','E', '\0'}; and you should be fine

Regards

Comment: Why this undefined behavior happens?Why it couldn't find the '\0' terminator? I must know why it happens to remember and learn from this mistake.

Comment: well you fill the Array with characters and so the \0 is not added at the end. The other way to have a char "array" is as Blupixy has used
char whatever[] = { 'a', 'b'} is just an array with exactly two elements whereas char something_else[] = "AB" is an array with three elements the last one is the \0. IMHO it's a better idea not to search for a \0 but to just loop as far as you 
#define LIMIT 3
for i = 0; i < LIMIT, i++ or the like

Comment: @MorHaham , when you write `char something[]="Something";`, the `\0` is automatically supplied whereas if you do `char something[]={'S','o','m','e','t','h','i','n','g'};` , the `\0` is not supplied at the end.

Comment: So how can you explain that in the second example the loop stopped when the array reached the '\0'?

Comment: I can't and I do not have to. Because everything I say is wrong. Undefined means everything can happen and if by chance it seems to work. That's fine by every mean.But that does not make the undefined bevhavior vanish. There's just ond thing to left for you as programmer. Don't write programs which undefined behavior. It will hunt you sooner or later and maybe it's years later. See the diverse safety problems in popular programs.....

Answer (score 4):

That array isn't null-terminated, you should insert a terminator yourself if you intend to use that loop

```
char array_ch[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', '\0' };
```